# Why can't I see DB tables when joining has_one assocation?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model

```
class Foo
  has_one :bar, -> { some_conditions }, class_name: "Foo", foreign_key: :foobar_id
end
```

Works great. But if I do this

```
Foo.joins(:bar)
```

Then some_conditions part breaks. After some testing, I've discovered, that trying to do anything with the DB inside that part gives me the MySQL error, stating that `Unknown table foos`.

Can someone provide explanation why is this happening?

EDIT: I have noticed, that it is somehow connected to the ActiveRecord_Relation, because calling "model" makes it ok, and all the AR methods are working fine.

Comment: please elaborate: How does the database schema for `Foo` and `Bar` look like? When `some_conditions` breaks, how what exactyl is `some_conditions`? What is the exact error message - including the SQL generated by Rails and full stacktrace?

Comment: We have only one table, which is "foos". Bar is self association on that same table (Foo is the only model).

some_conditions are not specific, as this problem can be reproduce in many ways (even order(:id) breaks it)

But, experimenting further, I have discovered that for some reason it did started to work. Anyway question remains open, what could be the cause of this?

Comment: It is difficult to help with the cause when we don't have any context to really go on including what breaks means or what `some_conditions` are. What if I told you I had 2 tools and they both work but under certain conditions one of them breaks. Then asked you Why this happens? How would you answer?